# Linq how to use a subSelect as a virtual table in FROM

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

There may be similar questions out here but none that I could find for doing a subSelect in the **FROM** clause as a virtual table.

Most of the columns I need are in **one** table.  There are a few columns needed from different tables that I cannot join on without getting a Cartesian join.

Here is my SQL query:

```sql
SELECT meter_name, a.loc_id, a.loc_name, a.facility_name, meter_type
FROM   meter_table, (SELECT  loc_id, loc_name, facility_name
                     FROM    facility_table
                     WHERE   id = 101) a
WHERE meter_id = a.fac_id
```

I have no idea how to convert this into Linq and it must be done tonight for a demo in the morning.

Comment: Please show us your existing LINQ attempt. Don't stress if it doesn't work - we just need to see where you are up to.

Comment: Well, my previous query used joins and it worked until the requirements changed 2 hours ago.  My research took me to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941452/1735836) which may be what I want but it's very complex and I'm not sure that it is what I need.  The damn code is on a machine that is locked down.  So I will need to retype it.  I will post as soon as I can.

Comment: Here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27442658/1704458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume this represents your `meter_table` within your database
 in this case each element of the list represents a record in the database table holding the appropriate attributes 
 i.e the table columns will become the properties of each object

```
List<Meter> meter_table = new List<Meter>();
```

Assume this represents the `facility_table` table you want to join with.
    same goes here, each element of the list represents a record in the database table holding the appropriate attributes 
    i.e the table columns will become the properties of each object

```
List<Facility> facility_table = new List<Facility>();
```

then perform the inner join like so:

```
var query = from m in meter_table
            join a in facility_table on m.meter_id equals a.fac_id
            where a.id == 101
            select new { meter_name = m.MeterName, 
                         loc_id = a.LocId, 
                         facility_name = a.FacilityName,
                         meter_type = m.MeterType
                       };
```

where `m.MeterName`, `a.LocId`, `a.FacilityName`, `m.MeterType` are properties of their respective types.

it's also worth noting the variable *query* references an *IEnumerable* of anonymous types. However, if you want to return an `IEnumerable` of  strongly typed objects then feel free to define your own type with the appropriate properties then just change `select new` to:

```
select new typeName { /* assign values appropriately */}
```

of the above query.